# Legendre polynomial integration, basic

Tags: legendre-polynomials

I want to evaluate $$\int_0^1x^2P_n(x)\,dx$$ but the only way out i see is by using $$xP_n(x)=\frac{nP_{n-1}+(n+1)P_{n+1}}{2n+1}$$ twice and since i got many $\int_0^1P_l(x)dx$,  i use $$P_l(x)=\frac{P'_{n+1}-P'_{n-1}}{2l+1}.$$ In the endm there a lot of terms with $P_k(0)$ with big constants with factorials before. Furthermore the $P_k(0)$ are known as $$\frac{(-1)^{l/2}l!}{2^l(\frac{l}{2}!)^2}$$ for (l) even, and zero to (l) odd.

There is a way of evaluating this without this long and tedious terms that dont cancel out?

Comment: use the fact that $P_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1)$ and then orthogonality of $P_n$

Comment: i.e. $x^2=\frac{2}{3}P_2+\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: @phdmba7of12 Are you sure that orthogonality of $P_n$ holds here? We don't integrate on $[-1,1]$ but on $[0,1]$. For instance, we have that $\int_0^1 P_1(x)P_2(x)~dx=1/8$.

Comment: According to Mathematica, the result seems to be
$$\int_0^1x^2P_n(x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4\Gamma(2-n/2)\Gamma((n+5)/2)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I will at least offer a solution for the even case. If $n=2k$ is even, then $P_n$ is an even function and $x^2P_n(x)$ is even as well. Thus, we would have

$$\int_0^1x^2P_{2k}(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1x^2P_{2k}(x)\,dx$$

We can explicitly write the $x^2$ in terms of Legendre polynomials, since

$$P_0(x)=1,\;\;\;\;P_2(x)=\frac{3x^2-1}{2}$$

Thus,

$$x^2=\frac{2}{3}P_2(x)+\frac{1}{3}P_0(x)$$

Thus,

$$\int_0^1x^2P_{2k}(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{6}\int_{-1}^1\left(2P_2(x)+P_0(x)\right)P_{2k}(x)\,dx$$

For $k\neq 0$ and $k\neq 1$, by the orthogonality of the polynomials this integral must be zero. Otherwise, we get some value, using the normalization constant of the polynomial, which is

$$\int_{-1}^1P_n(x)^2\,dx=\frac{2}{2n+1}$$

Thus, we have

$$\int_0^1x^2P_{2k}(x)\,dx=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{3} & : & k=0 \\
\frac{2}{15} & : & k=1 \\
0 & : & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.$$

For odd values of $n$, I can't see an obvious way of doing this without resorting to ugly formulae for the polynomials.